# Passing a pointer to function to find max float in an array of structs in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to print out the max price that is found in the array of structs in the function but it keeps giving me zero and not the max number in the array of structs.

Comment: In `find_company` your `i` variable equals to `4` after the first loop. You should probably assign it to `0` before starting the second loop

Comment: I just made that change and it is still giving me that the highest price is 0

Comment: `find_company` will never make it to `i==1`, since it always returns something during the `i==0` block.

Answer (score 1):

you return wrong way so loop can't run, with your loop like that, your function will return 1 if first element in array true, otherwise false, and code for maxprice don't run, your code should be like this

```
    int  ret = -1;
    for (...) {
        if (...) {
            ret = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    *maxprice = ...;
    for (...) {
        ...
    }
    return ret;
```